# HTML reader in C/C++ Win32?

Tags: c++, html, winapi

I'm parsing an internet service in my Win32 C++ application and i must convert the html to plain text, ommiting the html tags.
How can i do that? Which library do you offer?
Thanks

Comment: google for an HTML parsing library ... and you'll find something called libhtml :P ; if all you are doing is removing tags, you can write a parser yourself

Comment: Perhaps use a regular expression library to identify and remove the tags? For example the one in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)?